# How to set an object value within its prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the value of an object within its own prototype.
I have found some code that works:

```
Object.prototype.myFunction(){
    return 'It finally works!';
}
var i = 'hello world';
i = i.myFunction();
alert(i);
```

but it seems excessive and I'm sure there's another way.

Things I have tried that haven't worked:

```
Object.prototype.myFunction(){
    return 'It finally works!';
}
var i = 'hello world';
i.myFunction();
alert(i);
```

and

```
Object.prototype.myFunction(){
    this.randomVariable = 'temporary';
    this.randomVariable.parentNode = 'It finally works!';
}
var i = 'hello world';
i.myFunction();
alert(i);
```

and even

```
Object.prototype.myFunction(){
    this = 'It finally works!';
}
var i = 'hello world';
i.myFunction();
alert(i);
```

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: What language is _this_? Javascript?

Comment: Your answer up top is probably as good as it gets without doing something super hackish. Everyone that reads this will probably be wondering, though, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You say that `Object.prototype.myFunction(){ return 'It finally works!'; }` works, but that is highly unlikely, since it's invalid syntax and won't even parse.

Comment: It is considered an anti pattern to modify the Object prototype itself. Especially since everything in javascript is an object (if it isn't a primitive like string). So If you modify the Object prototype even Arrays and Function will have access to that prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

First, [you don't want to extend the JavaScript native Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes).  Second, I'm not sure what you mean by 'excessive', but if you want to change the value of a property in an object via its method, you can do as follow. Note that I'm trying to maintain the essence of your question:

```
var MyObj = function() {
 this.greet = 'It finally works!';
}

MyObj.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  this.greet = 'hello world!';
}

var i = new MyObj();
alert(i.greet);

//do whatever you want with this object i, when you're tired with it, you can call myFunction on it, and greet will change

i.myFunction();
alert(i.greet);
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way to change the value of an object within one of its methods. The code you found that works is the way to do what you are looking to do. Given that, I would just make `myFunction` its own function, without bothering to set it to `object`'s  prototype.